# HTML - How to put website online at specific time

Tags: html, upload

I've added a countdown timer on my website to create a buzz about a certain event.
Now I wanted a certain webpage to be online/uploaded at a specific time (12pm 31/12/14)

How do I do is automatically, so I don't have to manually upload it at the specific time.
Since I won't be near my laptop then.

Comment: 12pm - great! what timezone?

Comment: How about a cron job?

Comment: This depends on a lot of things. What kind of access do you have to the server? Can the server run some kind of server side code, eg. PHP? Do you have access to cron?

Comment: This is best suited for a CMS with a publish date/time on the content item. The ways to do it in HTML are hokey at best (you could use Javascript to turn a link on after a date/time, but users who turn off Javascript will never see it, and search engines could index the page unless you use robots.txt to prevent crawls - which after the go-live time, you're going to want to allow as well)

Answer (score 1):

Use server-side code to serve a different page before that time.